# is there way to convert daily predictions to hourly predictions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

```
#df_test.head(3)

    ID      Datetime
0  18288    26-09-2014 00:00
1  18289    26-09-2014 01:00
2  18290    26-09-2014 02:00

#df_test['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['Datetime'])
#df_test = df_test.set_index('Datetime')

Datetime             ID
2014-09-26 00:00:00 18288
2014-09-26 01:00:00 18289
2014-09-26 02:00:00 18290

# Converting to daily mean 
df_test_daily = df_test.resample('D').mean() 

# model.predict(df_test_daily)
```

After making the traffic predictions count on the daily data, how can we convert it to hourly predictions.

Comment: I understand your response to my answer, but still am not clear. Can you give an example?

Comment: If the datetimes you posted as example data are correct, you already have hourly predictions, right? They are an hour apart.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the D to H.

```
# Converting to daily mean 
df_test_daily = df_test.resample('H').mean()
```

More info here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects

Comment: we need to convert the daily predictions to the hourly. By resampling using 'H' on the daily data, we get prediction count only for 2014-09-26 00:00:00, 2014-09-27 00:00:00, and so on and not for all 0-23 hours.